# How to omit generation of views when creating controllers with context in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, scaffolding

I've created a TT file which overrides the default `"ControllerWithContext"` TT to be used for custom generated controllers.

The problem is when I create a controller it creates a set of views alongside the controller.

Is there a way to omit the creation of the views since I only need the model?

Answer (score 0):

rename your CodeTemplates => AddView folder before create controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can always omit the code what you need to do is when you are creating a controller you need to select the option as Empty controller rather than selecting the option as controller with edit and update. I hope this will solve your problem. and it wont generate the unnecessary view files.